# How to deal with DirectVmConsumerNotAvailableException

Tags: java, apache-camel, continuous-deployment

I have a Camel based application with `direct-vm` routes, from which I get sometimes `DirectVmConsumerNotAvailableException`s after redeployment from our continuous integration server. The redeployment is done using `Karaf`'s commands:

```
features:uninstall my-feature/snapshot-version
features:removeUrl mvn:my-package/my-feature/snapshot-version/xml/features
features:addUrl mvn:my-package/my-feature/snapshot-version/xml/features
features:install my-feature/snapshot-version
```

My feature consists of several bundles, the broken direct-vm route is between two of them.

Is there a way how to automatically reconnect from/to direct-vm route? Is there a better way how to redeploy Camel application? Is there a way how to detect broken routes before they get used?

Answer (score 1):

Since Camel 2.16 there is an option `failIfNoConsumers` you can set to `false`, if it is OK for you, to have some failing Exchanges, that usually appear at startup, when the bundle, defining the route is not yet loaded, but some other bundle, using an endpoint already is.
The disadvantage is, that during normal use, those errors are usually not acceptable and need handling.

I had the same problem once (prior 2.16), and wrote a custom error handler, which checks on `DirectVmConsumerNotAvailableException`, if it occurred during startup, and then silently discards the Exchange.

If you know the route, that initializes your Direct-VM endpoint and have access to the `CamelContext`, from the point, the exception occurs, you can check with `CamelContext.getRouteStatus(String id)`, if the route is already up and running...

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm currently using Camel 2.15.1 from JBoss Fuse. I'm gonna try to play with `block` and `timeout` options, looks promising.